# Вставить в середину строки другую строку

Tags: javascript

Допустим, у меня есть строка:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

А мне нужно получить такую:

```
++++++++++++++++++ТЕКСТ++++++++++++++++++
```

Как мне вставить другую строку ровно в центр этой, при этом сохранив объем символов?

Comment: "при этом сохранив объем символов" - не используйте слова, смысла которых не понимаете

Comment: а что не так с этими словами?

Comment: мне нужно вставить строку так, чтобы количество плюсов уменьшилось, и объем строки никак не поменялся

Comment: это обычная строка, можете вместо плюсов поставить что угодно

Comment: Это длиной называется. Куда вставлять нужно? в любое место в середине или есть какие-то условия?

Comment: я же написал пример

Comment: Представьте четыре плюса. Вставляем одну букву. Заменится второй или третий плюс на неё? Представьте три плюса. Вставляем десять букв, в итоге 10 букв без плюсов?

Comment: так мало значительно, если из 40-ка символов один в центре уйдет влево, либо в право

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function placeInCenter( str, substr ){
  let index = ( str.length - substr.length ) / 2;
  return str.substr( 0, index ) + substr + str.substr( index + substr.length );
}

console.log( placeInCenter( '+++', 'A' ) );
console.log( placeInCenter( '+++++', 'ABC' ) );
console.log( placeInCenter( '++++', 'A' ) );
console.log( placeInCenter( '+++', 'ABCDE' ) );
```